# Dropdown Animation for the menubar is not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to write my personal website. In this code for the navbar of the website, the animation doesn't work when the button is clicked for closing the menu. The button is only shown for the devices that has maximum 740 px width. Here is my code:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import styles from "./Navbar.module.css";
import { useState } from "react";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
    console.log("open changed " + open);
  };

  const handleCloseAnimationEnd = () => {
    console.log(" animation completed"); // Log when the animation completes
  };

  return (
    <nav className={styles.navbar}>
      <div className={styles.navbarName}>Mehmet Hasat Serinkan</div>

      <button className={styles.mobileMenuButton} onClick={handleOpen}>
        Menu
      </button>

      <ul
        className={`${styles.navList} ${open ? styles.open : styles.close}`}
        onAnimationEnd={handleCloseAnimationEnd}
        onAnimationStart={handleCloseAnimationEnd}
      >
        <li className={styles.navItem}>
          <Link href="/" passHref legacyBehavior>
            <a className={styles.navLink}>Home</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className={styles.navItem}>
          <Link href="/main" passHref legacyBehavior>
            <a className={styles.navLink}>About Me</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className={styles.navItem}>
          <Link href="/experiences" passHref legacyBehavior>
            <a className={styles.navLink}>My Experiences</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className={styles.navItem}>
          <Link href="/contact" passHref legacyBehavior>
            <a className={styles.navLink}>Contact</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

and the css module for this class is:

```
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  z-index: 100;
}

.navbarName {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.navList {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navItem {
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

.navLink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}

.navLink::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.navLink:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(0.5);
}

.mobileMenuButton {
  display: none;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
}

@keyframes slideDown {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 740px) {
  .navList {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    z-index: 99;
    
  }

  .navList.open {
    display: block;
    animation: slideDown 0.7s ease forwards;
  }

  .navList.open .navItem {
    margin: 1rem 0;
  }

  .navList.close {
    animation: slideUp 0.7s ease forwards;    
  }

  .mobileMenuButton {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.